# Ubuntu 16.04 Loop after Update

Tags: login

I had been login to my laptop and there was an update which came in with a prompt to restart. After the restart I can login through the GUI again. I had done all I could find by on google but I am still having the same issue.

I notice the following:

1. I can't `cd /home/user` - permission denied
2. `ls -l /home`: `drw------50 user user 4096 Feb 4 9:34 user (NOT drwx)`

   `ls -la ~/`: I can't find the .Xauthority file along the list

Comment: The directory should have the executable bit set. Run `sudo chmod 700 /home/user` to fix it, either from a Live-CD or if you can login as root directly on a console.

Comment: @Thomas: Wouldn't a laptop with a desktop rather need `chmod 755`?

Comment: Well, maybe worth another question. But IMO it depends on who you want to be able to browse your home directory and it is independent of being a server, workstation or notebook.